# Tkinter - Creating a square that follows my mouse location

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have to create a square around my pointer on the canvas. And I want that square to follow my pointer as I move it around.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)
f.pack()
c = Canvas(f,bg = "black")

while root:
    x = c.winfo_pointerx()
    y = c.winfo_pointery()
    c.create_rectangle(x,y,(x+10),(y+10),fill = "red")
    root.mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

Now when I run this the rectangle doesn't load.

Comment: Kindly add what you've tried so far regarding your query & what problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method won't work, because once you call `mainloop`, it waits for the window to close, so it will never get past the first iteration of the loop. And if you remove the `mainloop` from the loop, it will never reach the `mainloop` after the (infinite) loop.

The proper way to do this is to use [callback events](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-types.html). Also, you should [move the rectangle](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html), instead of creating a bunch of new ones. Try something like this:

```
def callback(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    c.coords(rect, x - 10, y - 10, x + 10, y + 10)

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root)
rect = c.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0)
c.bind('<Motion>', callback)
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```